# smoothening image boundaries for NxN kernel size

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing

In my open source project ( https://github.com/mmj-the-fighter/GraphicsLabFramework ) i am trying to add a image smoothening box filter for NxN kernel size. I have already implemented the algorithm for 3x3 kernel size. As you can see from the source code below I am not processing the image for edges. Using this logic, for a 5x5 kernel size I have to skip two rows or columns from top, right, bottom and left of the image. So the edges will not be blurred. Is there any other solution.
Here is the code:

```
/*applying a box filter of size 3x3*/
void blur_image(unsigned char *img, int width, int height)
{
    int n = width * height;
    int i, j;
    int r, g, b;
    int x, y;
    float v = 1.0 / 9.0;
    float kernel[3][3] =
    {
        { v, v, v },
        { v, v, v },
        { v, v, v }
    };
    unsigned char* resimage = (unsigned char *)malloc(width * height * 4 * sizeof(unsigned char));
    memcpy(resimage, img, width*height * 4);
    
    for (x = 1; x < width - 1; ++x) {
        for (y = 1; y < height - 1; ++y) {
            float bs = 0.0;
            float gs = 0.0;
            float rs = 0.0;
            for (i = -1; i <= 1; ++i) {
                for (j = -1; j <= 1; ++j){
                    float weight = (float)kernel[i + 1][j + 1];
                    unsigned char* buffer = img + width * 4 * (y + j) + (x + i) * 4;
                    bs += weight * *buffer;
                    gs += weight * *(buffer + 1);
                    rs += weight * *(buffer + 2);
                }
            }
            unsigned char* outbuffer = resimage + width * 4 * y + x * 4;
            *outbuffer = bs;
            *(outbuffer + 1) = gs;
            *(outbuffer + 2) = rs;
            *(outbuffer + 3) = 255;
        }
    }
    memcpy(img, resimage, width*height * 4);
    free(resimage);
}
```

Comment: Are you only interested in uniform weight, like the code you paired? Or do you want this to be generic? For uniform weights there are efficient algorithms that are independent of kernel size. You should also consider the case of separable kernels, which can be implemented more efficiently than in the generic case.

Comment: There is a lot written about boundary extension. What has your research turned up? Are you asking how to implement the extension, or are you still in the phase where you don’t know at all what to do with pixels near the image edge?

Comment: I don’t know at all what to do with pixels near the image edge.

Comment: Maybe read a tutorial, something like this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/imfilter-boundary-padding-options.html